# How to get distance from detected objects in autoware

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

When I use Yolo3 algorithm in Autoware with LGSVL simulation, it can detect objects and display on RViz (ImageViewePlugin) through topic `/detection/image_detector/objects`

How can I get distance from LGSVL simulator to detected objects and display them on RViz?

I checked the following nodes on Autoware:

- lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect
- range_fusion
- imm_ukf_pda_track
- naive_motion_predict
- costmap_generator
- astar_avoid
- pure_pursuit
- twist_filter

but it does not get the distance.

My environment:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Autoware (docker) 1.12.0 melodic.

Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336737/how-to-get-distance-from-detected-objects-in-autoware/) by [tiensu](https://answers.ros.org/users/45043/tiensu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2019-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could get and display distance on Rviz.

---

Originally posted by [tiensu](https://answers.ros.org/users/45043/tiensu/) with karma: 56 on 2019-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ShyamGanatra](https://answers.ros.org/users/38099/shyamganatra/) on 2021-08-27**:
Can you please tell, how did you get it displayed on RViz?